# innodb-read-only prevent mysql replication? Table 'gtid_slave_pos' is read only

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, innodb, read-only

I set up a couple of `maraidb v10.2.10` containers with the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/). Master can read/write and slave is read-only with this my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]
server_id=2
read_only=1
innodb_read_only=1
```

Replication was working well for a while but it stopped with the following error:

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: No
Last_Errno: 1942
Last_Error: Error during COMMIT: failed to update GTID state in mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1036: Table 'gtid_slave_pos' is read only
```

I added this line into slave's my.cnf and set it up again from the beginning but still got the same error.

```
replicate-ignore-table=mysql.gtid_slave_pos
```

Does this mean that Innodb can't replicate to `innodb-read-only` server?

Answer (score 1):

As well explained [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/looking-slave-consistency-say-yes-read-only-and-no-super-and-slave-skip-errors) slave should be read_only.
Are you sure that nobody is trying to write to slave?
Check if available the binlog.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm sure nobody tried to write to slave. The name of `gtid_slave_pos` seems to be used by slave itself to check the slave status. I believe slave itself wants to `COMMIT`. I thought I turned off the gtid_mode but mariadb doesn't have the variable. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-variable-differences-between-mariadb-100-and-mysql-56/#gtid_mode There will be a hint in here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/gtid/ but I'm not an English expart, so coudln't figure out it yet.

Comment: I added `slave_skip_errors=1942` but still got the same error. I start to think this as a mariadb's bug.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue. Looks like `innodb_read_only=1` prevents the replication.
If you only set `read_only=1` the replication is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you are looking for is read_only, not innodb_read_only. The latter isn't for the use case you are describing, it is intended for data recovery operations.